# How do I find out what my ip address was yesterday (or some day in the past)?

Tags: ip

I have the strange need to know what my public ip address was from yesterday. Is there a tool to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you use outlook, find an email sent on past days, and view "raw message" and look in the headers. You could possibly recover it from there.

If you use gmail, look at the bottom of the main mail page (it says "Last account activity, see DETAILS") You can look there too.

If you visited any sites you know the owner of, tell them to look through the logs at what time you visited them, and compare it to your User Agent. (Still not definite, but a good guess).

Comment: good suggestions - the only caveats I can think of are that using email headers may have varying degrees of accuracy, and the other methods will only show what the remote server thought your IP was (so if you need the public-facing IP they're great, if you need an internal network address they may not be so helpful unless you can get the info from an internal site)

Comment: @vore - Very true, but what other definite options are there :D? QUOTE: "...need to know what my public ip address was from yesterday" AKA RTFQ.

Comment: …which is why email headers have varying degrees of accuracy (the first Received: header is "Received from 10.0.0.1 by 10.0.0.2", then 10.0.0.2 hands it off to the public internet - we don't know what 10.0.0.1 was mapped to)

Comment: @vore - Okay, fair enough. The outlook I used to use was set up to directly contact the mail servers. I don't like the whole "download emails and have an upload queue" function, and "offline email" since it's compromizable. But in this case, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

If your DHCP client is logging the addresses it received you can examine the logs (without knowing what operating system you are using I can't give you any more specific guidance than that).

If your DHCP client is not logging its assigned address you may be able to contact your ISP and get this information, though they will probably ask why you need to know.

If you were manually assigning yourself addresses and didn't write it down you're probably out of luck.